# maven-pmd-plugin not identifying errors

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, pmd

I am trying to configue the maven-pmd-plugin.

I have added the following to my POM.xml:

```
    <reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>category/java/codestyle.xml/ControlStatementBraces</ruleset>
                    <ruleset>category/java/braces.xml</ruleset>
                    <ruleset>category/java/naming.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

and am testing against the following class:

```
package org.example;

import java.beans.BeanInfo;
```

public class Ct {

```
public int d(int a, int b) {
    if (b==0)
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    else
        return a / b;
}

public void loop(){


    while(1==1)
        System.out.println("sdfj");

}
```

}

I'm running the command with mvn pmd:pmd and the only error that is being reported is the unused import.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong as it should pick up more errors.

Comment: Cause you have added it in reporting ...you should make it as plugin and not in the reporting section.

Comment: @khmarbaise is right. Also, `category/java/braces.xml` and `category/java/naming.xml` don't exist in PMD.

Comment: The question is: Where are those given rulesets located in your project?

Comment: The official guide says to put it in reporting. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/usage.html I've tried with a number of other rules that I got from pmd site and it seems to pull XML files into the site folder but doesn't use and of the rules.